# Cant get jQuery ajax to work

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to convert my webpage to ajax but I cant get it to return anything.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){   
  // events
$("#test").click(function(){
    var myData;
    myData = makeDataVar();
    sendData(myData);
});     
  // functions
function makeDataVar(){
    return "name=joe&location=bostin";
}
function sendData(myData){
    alert("start mydata function");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.mypage.com/submitMe.php",
        dataType : "json",
        data: myData,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Data saved: " + nameMsg);
            alert("Data saved: " + locationMsg);
            alert("data saved: " + error);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error " + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
    alert("end mydata function");           
}
}); // end document.ready
//-->
</script>    
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="test" >Add New</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
$myVar = $_POST['name'];
$return['nameMsg'] = "thanks $myVar";
$myVar = $_POST['location'];
$return['locationMsg'] = "from $myVar";
$return['error'] = false;
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

I am getting all of my javascript alerts except for those inside the ajax statement (neither success or error). It is almost like my script is skipping over that one statement. I am not sure what I am missing here but I have spent a couple of hours trying to figure it out. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `type` should be lowercase, though I'm not sure that's your sole problem.

Comment: The success callback is only called when the server returns a successful 2xx code. Are you sure your server isn't throwing any errors?

Comment: @scurker - he'd get the error condition.  The only case that I know of is if he's trying to do something cross-domain without jsonp.  XHR just vanishes at that point.

Comment: Whoops missed that. The only thing not having type correct will do is make it send via `GET` instead of `POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My vote is that your variables inside the success callback are undefined, so the method doesn't compile or execute.

```
alert("Data saved: " + nameMsg);
alert("Data saved: " + locationMsg);
alert("data saved: " + error);
```

`nameMsg`, `locationMsg`, and `error` don't appear to be defined anywhere. This seems to masquerade as a method not getting executed sometimes, but Firebug or Chrome's developer tools should show you the error.

Does your success callback get executed if you don't try to use them?  Just do an

```
alert("foo");
```

and see if that works.

Comment: You are correct that fixed it. I needed to use msg.nameMsg because msg is my incoming parameter.  Thanks sometimes I overlook things after working on something too long.

Comment: I'm glad my 101-level javascript could help.  I've seen my callbacks fail to execute many times because of this!

Answer (score 1):

Are you hitting this from www.mypage.com?  If you're not, the XHR will just get eaten, with no return (error or success).

Also, you have a typo... the 'type' should be lower-cased, but that shouldn't cause your issue.

Comment: no i just changed the code to mypage.com for this post. I fixed the typo and refreshed my page still no go.

Comment: My question is... are you hitting the page from the same domain (and subdomain) that you're calling the AJAX from?

Comment: Time to pull out the packet sniffer.  You can use the net console in firebug/chrome/safari... or use an external one like Fiddler (win)/HTTPScoop (mac).  Although I don't think you're even getting to your server because you should get something back into one of the callbacks.  If you have a public URL, I'd be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ....
});
```

Use something like Firebug to inspect your JS for errors.

You also need to make sure that you're calling this from the same domain.

Comment: I vote for the javascript error inspection, too.  Have you defined `nameMsg`, `locationMsg`, and `error` in your page?

Comment: The user said above that he/she has already changed the type, but to no avail: "I fixed the typo and refreshed my page still no go."

Comment: I see that. I had this answer in before they commented that.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility your php script may be throwing a "notice" into the output, due to variable `$return` not being initialized, thereby not returning valid JSON

try

```
$return = array();
```

before using it

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want ? Just copy and paste this onto your html file and change the links..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){   
  // events
$("#test").click(function(){
    var myData;
    myData = makeDataVar();
    sendData(myData);
});     
  // functions
function makeDataVar(){
    return "name=joe&location=bostin";
}
function sendData(myData){
    alert("start mydata function");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.mypage.com/submitMe.php",
        dataType : "json",
        data: myData,
        success: function (msg) {
    //function returns json object not variables
            alert("Data saved: " + msg.nameMsg);
            alert("Data saved: " + msg.locationMsg);
            alert("data saved: " + msg.error);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error " + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
    alert("end mydata function");           
}
}); // end document.ready
//-->
</script>    
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="test" >Add New</button>

</body>
</html>
```